# Hide text in a region on every page

Tags: graphics, pdf, eso-pic

I want to "blank" a specified region of every page in a document. I thought of puting a blank image over that region of the document that I want hidden, but I don't know if this is possible.

I remember that the `eso-pic` package can insert background images to every page, but in my case I want the image to be on top of the text and hide it.

I need this only for printing (even if the text is still there, in the PDF file, behind the image -- that is not a problem).

Can this be done in LaTeX? Or there is need to process the final PDF file with some other software?

Comment: eso-pic does also foregrounds. Use `\AddToShipoutPictureFG{...}`.

Comment: @marmot: Is it possible to specify the absolute positioning of the image (assume that I have a blank image of the right size to cover the region)?

Comment: Sure. See e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410675/121799). There is a picture on top. Of course, you won't need all the transparency stuff....

Comment: Just let me tell you something: In theory everything a computer can do, can be done in TeX.

Comment: @digital-Ink: See [How to place a “floating text box” at a specified location in page coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24663/5764). You'll have to replace the text with an image, or with a `\colorbox`, or a coloured `\rule`... just something to cover whatever you want to cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example places a gray box on top of the content at a specified position relative to the upper left corner on every page of the document using the **`atbegshi`** package.

As requested by the OP, the box is only printed on paper, but not shown in the viewer, provided a PDF specification conforming viewer, such as Acrobat Reader or Foxit, is used. Package **`ocgx2`** is used to place the box on a print-only layer.

```
\documentclass{article}

% box color
\def\boxColor{lightgray}

% dimensions of the box
\def\boxWidth{0.25\paperwidth}
\def\boxHeight{0.25\paperwidth}

% position relative to upper left page corner
\def\boxOffsetX{0.3\paperwidth}
\def\boxOffsetY{0.3\paperheight}

\usepackage{atbegshi,xcolor}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \begin{ocg}[
      printocg=always,viewocg=never,
      showingui=never % also hide layer in the `Layers' navigation tab
    ]{veil}{veil}{false}%
      \hspace{\boxOffsetX}%
      \color{\boxColor}\raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+\boxOffsetY\relax}{\rule{\boxWidth}{\boxHeight}}%
    \end{ocg}%
  }%
}  

\usepackage{ocgx2} %PDF Layers
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Bla bla

\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The gray box still appears in the Page Thumbnails in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Can this be changed?

Comment: Seems to be an AR feature/bug. In Foxit, the box is hidden in the thumbnails as well.

Comment: @digital-Ink : I could fix the code in order to hide the box in the thumbnails view in AR too by setting initial visibility to `false`. Not quite logical, but works.